# How does energy compares to Momentum? (Besides the direction and the linear & quadratic relationship)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

This might be a very stupid question; We just learned about Momentum, I got really confused as to the creation and purpose of this unit. I know it "describes motion" with direction, but how so? I know the equations and relation to v (one linear, one quadratic...etc), but why invent this unit in the first place? This unit seems so abrupt and unrelated to all the other ones that were introduced before (Work, Force, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The question is not stupid at all.
Momentum is involved in Newton's 2nd law,
$$
\boldsymbol{F}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(m\boldsymbol{v}\right)
$$
But more intuitively, it is a measure of the push that an object will transfer you if it hits you. Even if it hits you very slowly, a heavy object can push you very significantly due to its mass. So it makes sense that the product of (mass)x(velocity) has physical meaning.
There are deeper connections farther along the road. You may learn some day that conservation of momentum is connected to the fact that space is the same everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've learned that Kinetic Energy can also describe how "hard" something hits you (the impact force), so what's the difference between the 2?

Comment: There are important differences. Consider an intuitive case like billiard-ball collisions. Momentum is always conserved if there are no external forces, but kinetic energy is not conserved if collisions are inelastic. Total energy, on the other hand, is on a similar level to momentum as to conservation. But not kinetic energy on its own. Kinetic energy is "allowed" to dissipate into internal motion; momentum is not, because it is a vector quantity.

Comment: This is very interesting, I am attempting to understand how scientists came up with this unit without knowledge of calculus, it looks like I lack something mandatory here xD. I will definitely check-in after I learn about integration and see if I can get a better understanding of how this unit came to be!

Answer (score 2):

Usually q quantity in physics that one bothered to name, it's because that quantity is very important.

Force is defined in terms of momentum, $\vec F =\dfrac{ \mathrm{d} \vec p}{\mathrm d t}$. This leads to the conservation of momentum, which states that if the net external force on a system is zero, the total momentum of that system will be conserved. The same cannot be said about kinetic energy (only in some cases KE is conserved).

A real life example of the importance of momentum is for instance a car crash. Suppose a car and and plastic bottle are travelling towards you at the same speed. Which one would hurt more? Obviously the car. Why? It has greater momentum. More momentum is transferred from the car that from the plastic bottle, which results in a greater force, which is what you feel.

Kinetic energy and momentum describe different quantities, both extremely important.

In terms of their difference, just think about them as different things that relate to motion. One is a scalar, the other is a vector. In the end, these quantities are both useful for describing many situations.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I guess my question is how does momentum compare to energy; obviously from a mathematical point of view, E''=F and P'=F; but how may one describe these relationships in a real-life scenario/without using calculus?

Comment: I don’t know that having a name necessarily makes a quantity “very” important. Derivatives of position with respect to time are named up to *tenth* order, yet nobody really talks about anything beyond jerk.

Comment: @Sandejo Indeed, but I was referring to the more "famous" quantities. Shouldn't have used "always"

Comment: @Shizan Wang $E''$ is not force. Force is a vector, energy is a scalar. Besides, to go from energy to something that looks like force you'd need to differentiate with respect to speed and then wrt time. Even that isn't force. That would be the rate of change of the magnitude of momentum. In 1 D motion for positive velocities that would correspond to force

Comment: KE and momentum just describe different important quantities. With calculus, you will be actually able to go from energy scalar to force vector (using Lagrangian mechanics).

Comment: I'm not sure what kinds of real life examples to describe these quantities you're looking for.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you all for these comments, these are really helpful for me to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question, especially since p=mv and T = m$v^2$/2, where T is the kinetic energy, we can write T = $p^2$/2m. So it appears there is a relationship between p and T, and when one is conserved so should the other be conserved so why use both? But this relationship only deals with the magnitude of p. As has been pointed out, p is a vector, **p**, so has magnitude and direction whereas T is a scalar and only has magnitude. There are situations where **p** is conserved while T is not, e.g. inelastic collisions, and situations where T is conserved and **p** is not, e.g. circular motion with constant speed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so would you say that momentum is the "part" of kinetic energy that cannot be lost in form of heat or sth else during collusion?

Comment: I'd be careful about making statements like that. Suppose two equal masses move toward each other with equal speed in a totally inelastic collision with no external forces so the masses stick to each other and don't move after colliding. There's some initial total kinetic energy but zero total momentum. After the collision there's zero total kinetic energy and still zero momentum. Can one say that the momentum was a part of the kinetic energy when it was always zero?